# How can I erase all the characters from the console?

Tags: java, windows, console, escaping, character

I want my program to be able to erase all the text it's printed. Every time it prints something, I call my `print()` method instead of `System.out.print()`, but then when I call the `erase()` method it doesn't seem to do anything in the Windows 7 console. I can't figure out what's up; I ran a test separately that confirmed that `\b` does erase characters but for whatever reason it won't work in `erase()`. Are the backspace characters erasing each other or something?

EDIT: I've run some more tests. It looks like \b won't overwrite newline characters. So I guess I need a way to do that.

```
public static int textLength = 0;

public static void erase() {
    for (int i = 0; i < textLength; i++) {
        System.out.print('\b');
    }
    textLength = 0;
}

public static void print(String s) {
    textLength += s.length();
    System.out.print(s);
}
```

Comment: If at all possible, you should be injecting what's actually used to print output.  For your erasure, are you attempting to erase what's been 'entered', or are you basically writing your own console?

Comment: I'm not writing my own console, I'm using the windows console. Everything the program prints gets its length added to textLength, then at the right time I print that number of backspace characters, which should erase everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cls");
```

**EDIT**:
Seems like this is not the solution you are looking for. When using

```
System.out.print('\b');
```

you need to be aware that this **does not erase** what was already printed. Instead each backspace **moves your cursor back** one character. To then actually erase what is there you need to overwrite it with some other text.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure if I want to entirely clear the console. Plus, that's OS-specific, which kind of defeats the purpose when you're working with Java. I'll use it until I find something better though.

Comment: See my edit. Does this help you? Think of System.out.print('\b'); as using arrow keys in a text editor.